# What is the Best Practice for Encoding Dates in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, rest

When designing a service that returns JSON to the browser (or server side JS), what is the "best" format for encoding dates in the resulting JSON response?

The data property should:

- require as little or no parsing to convert to a Date() object
- be sortable in the JSON representation itself

Returning the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC seems like it would be the best option but is not particularly human readable when looking at the raw JSON.

What's preferred in your experience and why?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to think about a single "Best Practice" here.  There are many possible requirements for managing date/time values, and different circumstances call for different solutions.

Comment: But this is fairly specific, consuming JSON from Javascript efficiently. I quoted "best" because it is certainly subjective and there is no one size fits all solution. I'm just trying to get some outside perspective and insight based on others experiences.

Answer (score 15):

Personally I'd go with [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (e.g. 2011-01-13T14:09Z).

It's well supported by virtually every programming language around, it's fairly easily human readable and, if you absolutely have to roll your own parser/formatter, it's fairly easy to deal with there too. It also has the sortable property you wanted.

Comment: I'd say using the strings is good because you can see the date, but can hurt performance except when you're sending lots of them. I worked with timesheet software that needed five Date objects per row; parsing strings was a bit too slow for people who were looking at monthly timesheets with 50 entries a day (total of about 1500 rows, or 7500 dates).

Comment: If you noticed it was slow parsing date strings and decided to measure the difference between using seconds since epoch vs. ISO 8601 for doing whatever it was you're doing with the JSON and found that doing the former really saved a significant percentage of time vs the latter, then yes, you probably should do seconds since epoch. I have a hard time believing that's the case, though, unless you're using an especially bad date parser.

Comment: For anyone reading this response (10 years later), parsing a date from a string takes almost 7x longer than parsing it from an epoch. I tested it in Node 16.8; creating a Date from an ISO8601 string took 0.0234ms, while creating a Date from an epoch number took 0.0035ms. So while ISO8601 is recommended for readability and standardization, if your application is performance-sensitive or deals with a large number of dates, you probably want to use epoch instead.